# How to pass parameters among different components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm wondering if there is any way to pass parameter (or variable) to different component (ex, if I click a button, and that button's onClick function can redirect me to another component, and that variable should be loaded instantly, and a different screen should be shown) I'm using react-router 3.0.0, and I hope to have similar functions like react-native

```
Actions.somepage({ls: variablename});
```

and when that page was loaded, there should be a function like `this.props.ls` 
to get that value.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?(I'm using   `this.context.router.push('/');` for routing)

Answer (score 0):

If you use react-router without a state manager (and react router v4), it is difficult to share state since there is no higher-level component that renders all your routes.  You can get around this by passing params along with your push with `this.context.router.push({ pathname: '/', params: yourObject})`

Answer (score -1):

If the component in question is a child of the component that has access to the variable / property it can pass it to the child like so

```
class myParentComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const foo = 'bar';
        <ChildComponent foo={foo} />
    }
}
```

ChildComponent now has access to foo on `this.props.foo`

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    // renders 'bar' in the div
    render() {
        <div>{this.props.foo}</div>
    }
}
```

If this is not the case, you need something to manage the state of your application. There are multiple implementations including flux, and my personal favorite redux. Or you can implement a more tradition MVC architecture, whatever you're used to. The important thing to remember is that `React` itself is only a view layer, not a way to manage an application.